# Create Object of a Class based on another Objects Attributes in Python

Tags: python, class, object, initialization

What would be the best practice to create a new object, which uses the attributes of an existing object of another class type in Python?

Let's say I have an object `MvsObject` of the class `MvsClass` and I want to create a new object of a different class that uses the attributes `densePointClouds` and `sparsePointClouds` and processes them with the methods of the class `PointCloud`.

Would the following approach be a "good practice" in Python?

```
class PointCloud:    

    def __init__(self, MvsObject):
        self.densePointClouds           = MvsObject.densePointClouds
        self.sparsePointClouds          = MvsObject.sparsePointClouds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is good. You could also use [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator in order to define two ways to build your class (in a "classical" way, or using another instance).

```py
class PointCloud:    

    def __init__(self, dense_points_cloud, sparse_points_cloud):
        self.dense_points_cloud = dense_points_cloud
        self.sparse_points_cloud = sparse_points_cloud

    @classmethod
    def from_mvs_object(cls, mvs_object):
        return cls(mvs_object.dense_points_cloud, mvs_object.sparse_points_cloud)
```

You would instantiate it like this:

```py
point = PointCloud.from_mvs_object(mvs_object)
```

Note also I renamed the attributes because using Python, it's preferred to use [snake case](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) to name your variables.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Do you know what the 'cls' actually does and what it is for?

Comment: @Miau It represents the current class, which is `PointCloud` in your case.